# Minimum number of draws in a Dirichlet distribution to obtain values above a threshold

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I am generating a flat Dirichlet distribution such that $\alpha_{1},....,\alpha_{k} = 1$. The distribution looks even for values of $ k < 5$ and 1.000.000 draws. However when I increase the value of $k$ for the same number of draws I struggle to reach extreme values of $x$, like $x > 0.95$. Thus I would like to know how to calculate the minimum number of draws such that $$p(x_i > 0.95) > 90 \%$$

Alternatively could I decrease the value of $\alpha$ to achieve the same goal?

Thank you

Comment: By "p(x_i > 0.95) > 90%", what precisely do you mean: there is at least one in one of the samples?

Comment: Yes. I want to know the probability that at least one of the draws will have one x_i > 0.95. And how many draws are needed to have this probability > 0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately all of the extremes are disjoint (and will remain so if you replace 0.95 with anything above 0.5), so there are no complications in calculating this.

Starting with the $\alpha = 1$ case:

For each $i$,
\begin{align}
P &= P(x_i \gt 0.95)
\\ &= \int_{x_i \gt 0.95} \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

Instead of the standard simplex, we've clipped off a tiny corner that is a smaller simplex. It's $0.05^{K-1}$ smaller, so we immediately get that $P = (0.05)^{K-1}$, without even having to think about any normalization factors.  You'll note that this becomes tiny as $K$ grows, even though the samples continue to be distributed over the $K$-simplex.

The chances of any of them being in their own extreme region is just $K$ times this, or $KP = K(0.05)^{K-1}$.  Finally, for *none* to be selected in $n$ tries is $(1 - KP)^n$, and for at least one, $1 - (1 - KP)^n$.  Set that to .9, solve for $n$ as a function of K, and you're done.

You can indeed influence things by using a different $\alpha$; a smaller $\alpha$ is more concentrated in the corners.  The math is hairier for general $\alpha$, as we no longer have a constant density, but I'm busy so I'll come back and finish this answer later.